# Symfony2 Doctrine2 Translatable Strange behavior

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony

I have a question about a strange behavior in the Translatable extension.

I have two tables, one called pages, and one called pages_translations in which I've the translation of my title|subtitle|text fields.

When I save for the first time a record, in the table pages I've title|subtitle|text fields that contains my default locale, and in the pages_translations both English, Italian, French etc...

If I change all the translation in my pages_translations table I've the right changed values, but in my pages tables I've have the old record with the first data saved.

This is not a big problem because when I call `getTitle()` or similar Doctrine takes the right value in the pages_translations table, but I don't like having the old values in my pages tables, there is a way to update also the pages table or (better) delete the title|subtitle|text fields because this fields doctrine really don't need.